# _.each find value in array return true or false. using underscore js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

//find value in array using function checkValue using underscoreJS _.each.
//return true, else false.

```
var helloArr = ['bonjour', 'hello', 'hola'];

var checkValue = function(arg) {
    _.each(helloArr, function(helloArr, index) {
        if (arg[index] === index) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
};
alert(checkValue("hola"));
```

Comment: great. Actually not. Explain your problem and what you're trying to do. And what we are supposed to.

Comment: Is this even a question? No it is not.

Comment: Write a function called checkValue that searches an array for a value. It takes an array and a value and returns true if the value exists in the array, otherwise it returns false.

var helloArr = ['bonjour', 'hello', 'hola'];

var checkValue = function(arr, val) {
  //checks if the val is in arr
}
Rewrite checkValue using _.each. Make sure that you have underscore.js included where you are running your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem with your code** is that, [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) will iterate through all the elements of the array and call the function you pass to it. You will not be able to come to a conclusion with that, since you are not getting any value returned from it (unless you maintain state outside `_.each`).

Note that the values returned from the function you pass to `_.each` will not be used anywhere and they will not affect the course of the program in any way.

But, instead, you can use [`_.some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some) as **an alternate**, like this

```
var checkValue = function(arg) {
    return _.some(helloArr, function(currentString) {
        return arg === currentString;
    });
};
```

But, a **better solution** would be, [`_.contains`](http://underscorejs.org/#contains) function for this purpose. You can use it like this

```
var checkValue = function(arg) {
    return _.contains(helloArr, arg);
};
```

But, since you have only Strings in the Array, **the best solution** would be to use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), like this

```
var checkValue = function(arg) {
    return helloArr.indexOf(arg) !== -1;
};
```

Comment: Exactly. No actual reason to use underscore for this specific purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful and eloquent code the exercise is for a _.each.

Comment: @thefourtheye sees all, Thank you. May the iteration always be in your favor. I am always amazed by the kindness and respect that occurs on this site. With great sincerity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var helloArr = ['bonjour', 'hello', 'hola'];

var checkValue = function(arr, val) {
  _(arr).each(function(value) {

         if (value == val)
           {return console.log(true);}
       else {return console.log(false);}
  });
};

console.log(checkValue(helloArr,'hello'));

/* Output 
false
true
false*/
```